# I want to make quiz app that I can update on daily basis

Tags: android

I want to make an `android` quiz app that I can update on daily basis.Like update daily General knowledge question answers .New section of question set date vice   . I am just a beginner in `android` and need some guidance . So please guide and give some reference that I can use .

Comment: I would do that everytime the quiz activity is opened the app checks if it needs to update and load some new data from the web service. This can be done by a version number or sice you want to update every day by the date. And then you just load the new data in your quiz or replace the old data...

Answer (score 3):

You can use Parse.com for such purpose. 
Here is link for [parse.com](http://parse.com/) for documentation [link](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide) for parse.com usage example take start from this site [link](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-simple-login-and-signup-tutorial/) last but not least do follow official android docs [link](http://developer.android.com/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

As you are saying you are new to `Android` so keep it simple just make the app to fetch the data from server. The other way is to store the data in `SQlite` and make your app run offline also.

As you have asked **I can update on daily basis**
So if you want to updates the question then you can do that from your server itself but if you want to update your app then you need to make your app in generalized manner thinking of your future updates, so that you can easily integrate the future functionalities whenever you needed.

Comment: I want add new section of questions (10 to 20)every day ......Like daily  to General Knowledge ...............

Answer (score 0):

for starters, keep the code and data separate, so you can trigger a fetch from a webserver (in XML or whatever format) with the day's quiz data, then parse and display it from your program. and cache it in a text file so you have something to use in case there is no web connection; nobody likes an app that just hangs.