# Database for Android App

Tags: android, database, sqlite

How and where I can maintain my DB for my android app. I know we can use sqlite DB for android apps but, I don't have any idea of Storing the DB at some other location and then accessing it on the app.

**Example Structure:**

[image]

I want to know, where and how we can have DB at some different point of location, Do I need to buy space or rent? Or there are any other ways (Having DB Server at my own Desktop and accessing it via IP address. Will there be any difficulties or dependencies)  I believe we can access it by creating a connection to the Db and writing queries to fetch by using Http Get and Post or Put methods.

If yes, then can we use SQL Server Management studio 2008 or what would be the simplest & the best to work with.

Comment: there are many online databases available. Just Google :)
You can also create your own DB server, that would require some work though.

Comment: upload your database on google drive by giving option to import/export

Comment: @Calvin : Is it possible that we can upload Complete DB to google Drive? I was unaware of it totally.. Any tutorial or reference available?

Comment: @SonamG you want to centralise you database or just want the user be able to access their data? https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder. Parse is also a well known if you are looking for centralized database

Comment: @Calvin : I wish to make the DB as centralised because I dont want my app users to loose their data locally on their smart phones, moreover they would be accessing this centalised DB data in encrypt and decrypt format. Then is it right thing to do? Store data in encrypt format and then decrypt when they retrieve it?

Comment: @SonamG in that case you should go with parse. about encryption, i am not the right guy to answer, but i guess communication over secure channel should suffice most common security needs, however it depends on you implementation requirement and the kind of application you are working on.

Answer (score 3):

Use [parse.com](http://parse.com) as a backend services.Easy to use and simple. follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34460701/5275639)

Answer (score 3):

Use realm, please.
https://realm.io/

It is much easier comparing to sqlite.
You can check the usages at https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/